# Can I close mobile menu on click for anchor links in Joomla project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this small Joomla project and I need help with the mobile menu. The anchor links just scroll but the menu doesn't close. Is there any script I can add to the index.php?

Those are my menu classes:

```
<div class="menu_mobile">   
<ul class="nav menu mod-list">   
<li class="items">      
    <ul class="nav-child unstyled" style="display: block;">   
    <li class="item-1"><a href="/anchor-link#link1">anchor link 1</a></li>   
    <li class="item-2"><a href="/anchor-link#link2">anchor link 2</a></li>   
    <li class="item-3"><a href="/anchor-link#link3">anchor link 3</a></li>    
    <li class="item-4"><a href="/anchor-link#link4">anchor link 4</a></li>    
    <li class="item-5"><a href="/anchor-link#link5">anchor link 5</a></li>   
    <li class="item-6"><a href="/anchor-link#link6">anchor link 6</a></li>    
    </ul>    
    </li>       
</ul>    
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution:

```
//gives command on click to close the menu and go to the anchor link location  
    jQuery('.menu_mobile ul li a').click(function(){ 
        jQuery("div.menu_mobile ul").css('display' , 'none'); 
        jQuery("div.menu_mobile ul"). removeClass('nav menu mod-list'); 
    
    //reloads the page without loosing the anchor link location 
        jQuery(".mobile-menu").click(function() { location.reload() 
        }); 
    });
```